# How to call $C^1$ functions with Lipschitz derivatives

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Is there a standard terminology for functions which are differentiable with Lipschitz partial derivatives (from an Euclidean space to another)?

It seems that semiconcave functions don't exactly work, as a semiconcave function can be non-differentiable.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Usual notation is $C^{1,1}$.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it is the right answer

Answer (score 2):

I saw "Lipschitz smooth" used for this purpose a few times. This terminology makes sense, but unfortunately many authors use this term as a synonym for *Lipschitz continuity*. So I can't recommend its usage.

Saying "a $C^{1,1}$ function" or "a function with Lipschitz gradient" is easy enough and unambiguous.